# Dc.js double grouping

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to dc.js. Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to make a bar chart, by counting the appearances of unique emails, x-axis is number of appearance groups, and y-axis will be number of unique emails fall into the occurrences group.(crossfilter will be involved so it will do auto grouping/counting based on date I am selecting)

My data set

```
email         date
a@gmail.com   1/3/2015
a@gmail.com   1/5/2015 
b@hotmail.com 1/4/2015
b@hotmail.com 1/5/2015  
c@msn.com     1/3/2015
d@gmail.com   1/3/2015
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "double grouping"? This looks like an ordinary crossfilter group with the default counting reduction to me.

Comment: You are the expert but it doesn't seem like an ordinary group reducing to me, I can just reduce and group by date but that is not what I want. I want them grouped in number of of appearances. Or am I overthinking here, care to share the code? Thanks.

Comment: Where should the date be displayed for selection, in this chart or in another one?

Comment: The date will be in the another graph. So the graph i have problem with, x-axis is the number of occurrences groups, and y-axis will be number of unique emails fall into the occurrences group.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are indeed overthinking it.  ;-)

Please comment if I'm off base here, but I think you are simply talking about grouping by email and reducing by count.

So you should be able to simply do

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.email; });
var group = dim.group();
```

and pass the dimension and group to your bar chart.  (Reducing by count of rows is the default behavior.)

Then you will have another chart which has a dimension on `d.date`.

This is the exactly the use case crossfilter is designed for.

Maybe the confusion is the crossfilter definition of "dimension".  You don't actually need a dimension for each dimension of your chart, just the dimension you brush on.

You use a crossfilter dimension for each column you want to group and filter on, or each column you want to observe filters on.  The reduction produces the Y axis values in most cases, and there is no crossfilter dimension needed for it.

Comment: Yes. Please try it out.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question here; an example of desired output would have helped. Performing a group on the results of a group is not supported, and building another crossfilter on the results of another one would not work if you expect filtering to work on the first instance.